# Replace Unloader Line on Air Compressor

Tags: repair, valve, air-compressor

I am trying to replace a broken unloader line on an air compressor I received from a family friend. After pulling off the cover it looks like a mouse may have chewed through the teflon line. I have purchased a replacement line but am having difficulty replacing the tubing in the existing valves. I would like to know how to reuse the valves or what replacements I need to get.

Unloader valve attachment:
[image]

Tank side attachment:
[image]

Compressor model info:
[image]

Close up of tank side valve:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line looks more like LDPE ("Alkathane") than PTFE ("Teflon") to me.

To release the line press the collar/cuff firmly towards the fitting (perhaps use an open end wrench) then pull and jiggle the line.

Installation is the reverse of removal, press the collar in and insert the line.

If the fitting has crud inside it it may not want to let go.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out great.